How to fix "Pending jobs in the event queue"
Shopify is new for me. I have created product-discount custom app using node js. I want to call GraphQL query for get customer all tags.
`
Note : below request working fine in post-man
File = run.js
let query =  `{
        customer(id: "gid://shopify/Customer/727xxxxxx1665") {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
          email      
          tags
        }
      }`;

    let config = {
      method: 'post',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: 'https://xxxxxx-xxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json',
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'shpat_d9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        query: query,
        variables: {},
      }),
    };

    async function runQuery() {
      console.error("----call make request-----");
      try {
        const response = await axios.request(config);
        console.error(JSON.stringify(response.data.data.customer));
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    }

    runQuery(); 


====================================================================
File = run.graphql
query RunInput {
  cart {
    lines {
      quantity
      merchandise {
        __typename
        ...on ProductVariant {
            id
            title
            product{
              id
              title
              vendor
            }
        }
      }
    }
    buyerIdentity{
      customer{
        displayName
        email
        id
      }
    }
  }  
}

When I run code then I get 2 error. Can you guys tell me how to fixed this error.
`1. Pending jobs in the event queue.
2. Scheduling events is not supported when the experimental_event_loop cargo feature is disabled.

you can't do asynchronous operation in the run.js file. If you want to check the customer tag, you can proceed from the documentation here.
With cart -> buyerIdentity -> customer -> hasAnyTag, you can check whether the tag you want exists in the user or not.
You need to use graphQL input for this. You can check the documentation here.
